# HTML Format in .Net TextBox

Tags: asp.net

How I can display HTML formatted text in .Net TextBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible

check this : http://www.freetextbox.com/

or

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/RichTextBox.aspx

But you can go for the HTML editors like fck editor to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You might also look into extending the TextBox control to allow HTML syntax formatting and highlighting.  I don't know how difficult or easy this might be, but it would certainly be an interesting learning experience.  If you're not looking to "roll your own" then probably one of @Pranay's suggestions is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have to `EDIT` the displayed formatted text, its easy **use a literal control**,
but if you have to be able to change the info, you would need a control that can handle html.

I use `FreeTextBox`, but there are many.
Be aware of the dangers of allowing HTML to be edited in your page.... this is a weakspot that hackers love...
(you have to set `validaterequest=false` in each page that contains a HTML edit control
Bert

Answer (score 0):

It you're in ASP, use a literal control. If you're creating an application you can use a WebBrowser control. Looks the same as a large textbox, but can accept html formatting.